# How to use OpenLayers 3 with Proj4js

Tags: openlayers, gis, projection, openlayers-3, proj4js

I'm working on a map viewer project and used openlayers 2 before this. Now I have to use OpenLayers 3 and map viewer app should support many different projections because I have wms and wfs layers from different sources and projections. I've found examples that use openlayers2 and proj4js. But I couldn't find explicit example for using ol3 and proj4js. What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that sometimes, like when using OpenLayers 3 and proj4 in Angular 2 using webpack, one needs to explicitly tell OL3 where to find it:

```javascript
import * as proj4 from "proj4";
import * as ol from "openlayers";
...
ol.proj.setProj4(proj4);
```

When all is fine, then after defining a projection, `ol.proj.get` should return it:

```javascript
proj4.defs("EPSG:28992", "...");
if (!ol.proj.get('EPSG:28992')) {
    console.error("Failed to register projection in OpenLayers");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Spent 2 days trying to figure out why proj4.defs wasn't setting my custom projection.  About to give up and a random last ditch search led me here, and what do you know....  setProj4(...) was the bloody solution.  NONE OF THE OL DOCS Mention this :-(

Comment: PPS: This is with the current ver of OL4 that's in NPM at the date of this comment being written, so it's still the same even since OL3

Comment: Seeing/using this if statement helped me trouble shoot, even though this wasn't directly related to my issue.

Comment: With openlayers 4 and typescript, I can't seem to get a reference to either the ol object or ol.proj, anyone having this working?

Comment: Ah whoops, I'm on OL5 beta, where it looks like they either got rid of setProj4, or haven't implemented it yet, but you can call register manually and it works again:
http://openlayers.org/en/beta/apidoc/module-ol_proj_proj4.html

Comment: @chrismarx I found the following in a branch in which I tried to migrate from OL4 to using modules (`npm install ol` rather than `npm install openlayers`) and OL5 beta: `import setProj4 from 'ol.proj.projection'`. However, I stopped that migration as I could not get the typings to work, so I might not have tested that specific part. Also, maybe your approach is actually to be preferred.

Answer (score 3):

This example demonstrates how to use proj4js with ol3: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.3.0/examples/wms-image-custom-proj.html

Basically using proj4js in OpenLayers 3 works transparently. You need to throw the srs definition at proj4js first, and then you can use the projection right away:

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:21781","+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=600000 +y_0=200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=660.077,13.551,369.344,2.484,1.783,2.939,5.66 +units=m +no_defs");
var zurich = ol.proj.transform([8.55, 47.366667], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:21781');
```

Comment: For more background information, you can also read http://ahocevar.net/2014/07/10/proj4js-2-2-x-with-ol3.html.