# angular & migration openlayers to ol & proj4js

Tags: angular, html-lists, openlayers, proj4js, proj

Tried to migrate an angular-based project using openlayers away from deprecated [openlayers-npm-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openlayers) to recommended [ol-npm-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ol). By debugging i realized that i had a problem with the previously still working integration of [proj4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proj4).

After two days of following different approaches, trying this and that, realizing that in that special combination of libraries the problem seems to result from a lack of typings for the new ol-package.

What i now can confirm - and hope it helps others (i can't comment to [SO-Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29027295/how-to-use-openlayers-3-with-proj4js) yet) - is, that the support for proj4 is not yet existing in [@types/ol:'4.6.2'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/ol), but in [@types/openlayers:'^4.6.12'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/openlayers).

**So utilizing proj4 to provide different projections to openlayers using dependencies**

```
"ol": "5.2.0",
"@types/openlayers": "4.6.12",
```

will work for the following code-snippet, but `ol` combined with `@types/ol` won't:

**imports**

```
import * as ol from 'openlayers';
import * as proj4x from 'proj4';
const proj4 = (proj4x as any).default;
proj4.defs([
  [ 'EPSG:25832', '+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs' ],
    ...
]);
```

**constructor**

```
ol.proj.setProj4(proj4);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to avoid @types/openlayers completely and resort to @types/ol i eventually came up with the following:

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "proj4": "2.4.4",
    ...
```

**app/.../@types/ol/proj/proj4.d.ts** (manually created another typefile below app-folder)

```
export namespace ol {
    namespace proj {
        function setProj4(proj4: any): void;
    }
}
```

**importing & definitions within eg. a component**

```
import proj from 'ol/proj';
import * as proj4x from 'proj4';
const proj4 = (proj4x as any).default;
// Two example-projections (2nd is included anyway)
proj4.defs([
    [ 'EPSG:25832', '+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs' ],
    [ 'EPSG:4326',  '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs' ]
]);
```

**within constructor** - finally registering proj4 with ol

```
proj.setProj4(proj4);
```

Answer (score 1):

The OpenLayers 5 does not have setProj4 method anymore but instead the register method in the [ol/proj/proj4](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_proj_proj4.html) module. So, I followed the solution by @user10324080 and also discussion [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/15663) and came to following solution with Angular 6:

1. Added the following lines to end of the CompilerOptions in the tsconfig.js file:

   `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop":true`
2. I created the file `@types/ol/proj/proj4.d.ts` and added in it:

   `export function register(proj4: any): void;`
3. In the .ts file where the map was created I added:

   `import { fromLonLat } from 'ol/proj.js'
    import {register as proj4register } from 'ol/proj/proj4'
    import proj4 from 'proj4';
    proj4.defs([[ 'EPSG:3067', '+proj=utm +zone=35 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs']]);
    // Constuctor:
    proj4register(proj4);
    // ngOnInit:
    var view = new View({
       projection: 'EPSG:3067',
       center: fromLonLat([27.47, 64.88], 'EPSG:3067'),
       zoom: 5
    });`

I had installed the following versions of the libraries and of the type definitions:

```
"ol": "^5.2.0",
"proj4": "^2.5.0",
"@types/ol": "^4.6.2",
"@types/proj4": "^2.3.4"
```